# DAX function to check the amount of dates that is greater than another set of dates in 2 different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently doing an internship where I have been asked to make a few visuals in Power BI

I've searched around, tried a couple of things. But the truth is I am very much a beginner at coding and functions in general. Only had basic courses of different languages during my education and to be fair, it's a bit outside my scope of work.

So I have 2 columns I need to compare in order to find out how many dates in column 2 that is greater than the dates in column 1

So I'm imagining something like:

```
Measure = IF[(Investments(Expected closure)]<[(Investments(Actualclosure)]
```

Basically I want an overview of how many investments have a later closure date than expected.

Next thing would possibly be to create a boxplot showing the distribution (by how far we are off).

I know this is very basic, and possibly not formulated in the best way possible, please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calculated column as a flag to identify if actual date > expected date and then count the flag.

Flag = IF('Table'[Act] > 'Table'[Exp], 1, 0)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZWYp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. Be sure to read to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for posting questions.

For your questions, you can use the following code. You are filter the table with your logical expression with `FILTER` and then you count the lines of a column with `COUNTA`.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTA('Investments'[Actualclosure]),FILTER(ALL('Investments'),'Investments'[Actualclosure]>'Investments'[Expected closure]))
```

Hope this solves your problem.